# How to suppress(remove) x tick labels of certain groups when using ggplot2 facet_wrap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

Hi I have graph like this. As you can see I have chunky x tick labels in mathematical forms.

```
#example data
data<-data.frame(group=rep(c("Group A with a long name1","Group B with a long name2",
                         "Group C with a long name3", "Group D with a long name4",
                         "Group E with a long name5"), each=70),
             method=rep(c("method1","method2","method3","method4","method5","method6","method7"),times=50),
             estimate=c(rnorm(70, 40, 7), rnorm(70, 60, 10),rnorm(70, 150, 20),
                        rnorm(70, 400, 80),rnorm(70, 300, 65)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(method, estimate))+
geom_boxplot()+
facet_wrap(~group, nrow=5, ncol=1, scales="free")+
xlab(NULL)+
ylab(bquote('estimate ('~individuals/km^2~')'))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=expression(over('M*',A[ns]),frac('M*',ESA[sr]),
                                 frac(M[Ch],A[ns]),frac(M[Ch],ESA[sr]),
                                 frac(M[0],A[ns]),frac(M[0],ESA[sr]),
                                 sr[0],'sr*'))+
theme_bw()+
theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "italic", size=12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=18, margin=margin(10, 0, 0, 0)),  #margin(top, right, bottom, left)
    axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, size=8, vjust=0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, size=14, margin=margin(0, 10, 0, 0)),
    axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, size=8),
    plot.title = element_text(colour="#990000", size=18),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    plot.margin=unit(c(0.3,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Since the labels are redundant. How do I turn off the x tick labels of group A,B,C,D, and only keep those of group E's? I sincerely appreciate any comments and help.

Comment: Editing `facet_wrap` to have free y axis will tell ggplot to let y vary among plots but will keep x the same. The edit: `facet_wrap(~group, nrow=5, ncol=1, scales="free_y")`

Comment: OMG, that easy? I should have tried that earlier. Thanks @oshun.